# Does redis pipe mode block on mass insertion?

Tags: redis

Once redis receives a piped file, will that redis instance block for all the commands as if it were one large transaction?

If not, can I wrap subsets of commands in the piped file in MULTI/EXECs?

The documentation on https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once redis receives a piped file, will that redis instance block for all the commands as if it were one large transaction?

Redis may interleave other operations between the pipelined ones.

> If not, can I wrap subsets of commands in the piped file in MULTI/EXECs?

Definitely. Do that when you require "atomicity" of a block of operations.

> The documentation on https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert isn't entirely clear.

True, but reading about [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) and [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) provides the whole picture.

Comment: Thank you! I was unclear on the overlap between pipe mode and pipelining. I'll look into the pipeline documentation now.